# QLineEdit: Change clearButton

Tags: qlineedit

When I set clearButtonEnabled= true, clearButton looks blurry. Is there any way to change the size of clearButton or to customize it with another icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I found this workaround:

```
QHBoxLayout *pSearchLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
pSearchLayout->addStretch();
pSearchLayout->addWidget(ui->pushButton);
pSearchLayout->setSpacing(0);
pSearchLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
ui->lineEditSearch->setLayout(pSearchLayout);
```